# GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN not acting properly

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) Google Developer Guide for implementing Google Sign-In into my app. And when I create the GoogleSignInOptions object and use the option `DEFAULT_SIGN_IN` everything works fine. However I need to use `DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN` and when I change that in the code, it no longer works properly and gives me a "signinresult:failed code=12501" code. Here is my only Activity on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/KVVEpj1e

Comment: Can you share what are the errors you are getting? Or what is your expected output?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I get a "signinresult:failed code=12501" but I've tried some of the solutions for that code and those dont work either

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure to outsource your app id to a resource file.

```
<!-- This works -->
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
     android:value="@string/app_id" />

<!-- This is returning an error -->
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
     android:value="12345678" />
```

Comment: This worked for me. Seems kinda broken if you can't pass the ID directly?

Answer (score 1):

It may be beneficial to review the [setup](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) page for Google Play Games Services as well as the [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting) page.

You will find that there are many reasons why you may be getting this error.

Below is a summary:

- You must add a game to the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) through the Games Services tab.
- Then you must link your app to that game.

  - When you do this, be sure the package name you enter exactly matches the package name in your AndroidManifest.xml.
  - As DEFAULT_SIGN_IN works for you, your client ID is probably already properly configured. Those who have not done this should refer to the above setup link for more detail.
- Next, add your application ID to your AndroidManifest.

  - your application ID is a 12-13 digit number that can be found on the Linked apps page
  - create a string resource for your application ID
  - add the following to your manifest within the application tag

    > ```
    > <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    > android:value="@string/app_id" />
    > ```
- Finally, add testers to your game.

  - Go to the Testing tab for your game in the Games services.
  - Add the emails of all accounts that you are using to test.
  - take a break for 30 minutes to be sure all the new testers are processed.

After all that, it may be worthwhile to check out the Games-specific [sign-in guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin).